# Writing a debugging statement

Tags: java, debugging

I had a mock exam and i'm going over some of the questions that came up. One being debugging.

The question read this:

[image: question text]

I wasn't sure how to answer it, the only thing i could think off was breakpoints and then using the eclipse to do the work. Could anyone give suggestions for what could have been considered answer for that question?

Comment: Please rewrite the question into the question, instead of posting a image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is most likely a lot more simple than that, I do not think the teacher refers to an actual Debug execution of the code, but more of a low-tech debug.
Thus a simple

```
System.out.println("ListSize: "+list.size());
for(Object o : list){
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

Would most likely be the correct answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I've got the real exam in a couple days. It's an open book, which i've never sat before. Any tips for prewritten notes for any future questions alike to this that come up ?

Comment: Well not really, just go through as many questions as possible, and if your answer seems too complicated, it probably is ;) Good luck^^